# Looping through files and saving as new file in r

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I've been trying to figure out a way to loop through a bunch of "csv" files that contain absorbance data. The file name reads as: Plate"x" 0000000.csv - the "x" is a plate number and the 0's represent a unique code consisting of time and date of observation. The goal is to run through each of the 269 files in my source folder and calculate some values consistently. I have the code done for the calculations. However, I am having trouble getting r looping through all of the files, applying the calculations, and then saving to a new file the output as a csv file in  a new folder as: Plate"x" 000000.csv

```
 wd = 'C:/Users/anadamsk/Documents/GRAD/DATA/Ecolog Plates' 

setwd(wd)

dirs = dir(getwd())

for (i in 1:269){

  #absfiles = list.files(pattern = "*.csv") # list abs files

plate <- read.csv("C:/Users/anadamsk/Documents/GRAD/DATA/Ecolog Plates/absfiles", ".csv", sep="/")

  #for (j in 1:269) 

    #u_IDs = as.data.frame(strsplit(absfiles[j], '[.]'))

    #unique_ID = as.character(u_IDs[1])

#plate <- u_IDs

#plate <- fread('C:/Users/anadamsk/Documents/GRAD/DATA/Ecolog Plates/absfiles')
#plate1 <-data.table(plate)
#str(plate)


colnames(plate)[1] <- "Well.ID"
colnames(plate)[3] <- "Absorbance"
#str(plate)

setDT(plate)[, Well.ID:=Well.ID[1L] ,cumsum(Well.ID!='')]
#str(plate)str()

plate[,Well.ID:=as.character(Well.ID)][Well.ID == "BLK", Well.ID := "111BLK"]

plate <- plate[,ID:=substr(Well.ID,4,6)]

plate <- plate[,Group:=ID]
plate <- plate[,Group:=as.factor(Group)]
plate <- plate[Group == "BLK", Group := "0"]
plate <- plate[,Group:=as.character(Group)]
plate <- plate[,Group:=as.numeric(Group)]
plate <- plate[Group > 0.9 & Group < 31.1, Group:= 1]
plate <- plate[Group > 31.1 & Group < 62.1, Group := 2]
plate <- plate[Group > 62.1 & Group < 93.1, Group := 3]
#str(plate$Group)




b1<-plate[Well %in% c("A1"),Absorbance]
b2<-plate[Well %in% c("A5"),Absorbance]
b3<-plate[Well %in% c("A9"),Absorbance]

#group_1<-plate[,abs.c:=Absorbance-b1]
#group_2<-plate[,abs.c:=Absorbance-b2]
#group_3<-plate[,abs.c:=Absorbance-b3]

plate[Group %in% c(1), abs.c:=Absorbance-b1]
plate[Group %in% c(2), abs.c:=Absorbance-b2]
plate[Group %in% c(3), abs.c:=Absorbance-b3]

plate[Group %in% c(1), AWCD:=mean(abs.c)]
plate[Group %in% c(2), AWCD:=mean(abs.c)]
plate[Group %in% c(3), AWCD:=mean(abs.c)]

plate[Group %in% c(1), Odi:=sum(abs.c,c(1))]
plate[Group %in% c(2), Odi:=sum(abs.c,c(2))]
plate[Group %in% c(3), Odi:=sum(abs.c,c(3))]

plate[Group %in% c(1), Pi:=abs.c/Odi]
plate[Group %in% c(2), Pi:=abs.c/Odi]
plate[Group %in% c(3), Pi:=abs.c/Odi]

plate[Group %in% c(1), sumpi:=Pi,c(1)*(log(Pi,c(1)))]
plate[Group %in% c(2), sumpi:=Pi,c(2)*(log(Pi,c(2)))]
plate[Group %in% c(3), sumpi:=Pi,c(3)*(log(Pi,c(3)))]

plate[is.na(plate)] <- 0

plate[Group %in% c(1), H:=sum(sumpi,c(1))]
plate[Group %in% c(2), H:=sum(sumpi,c(2))]
plate[Group %in% c(3), H:=sum(sumpi,c(3))]


H. <- plate[!duplicated(H),]
H. <- H.[!NA]
platechar <-as.character(H.)
#dir.create("./H_Values_Plates")
file=H.(paste("./H_Values_Plates/",".csv",sep="/"))
}
```

Comment: Without data, it's difficult to provide you with an answer that work. Question: what is H ? it appears out of nothing at the end of your loop.  Remark: normally, the function to save to csv files is write.csv. I would do a `write.csv(H., file = paste("./H_Values_Plates/",".csv",sep="/"))``

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As it's written, it's unclear what the problem actual is. Also, there are too many lines of code. Please, [edit] your code to the bare minimum which reproduces the problem. See [mcve] for guidance. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. H is a variable showing diversity index of the plate. Ending it with a write.csv like you suggested seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

`paste('Plate',i,'000.csv', sep = '')` in your loop with `i` taking values that you need should allow you to loop through. you seem to have a decent grasp on what you're doing in the loop. just use this to get at all the files

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's almost there. My script just doesn't want to end the loop now.